# flask with many buttons and database update

Tags: python, html, flask, forms, http-post

I am trying to make a web app like a mini-tweets. The posts are pulled out from a database and I want to have an 'up vote' button for each post, like the following picture.

[image: posts]

Each post has an `id`, `author`, `body`, and `likes` property. When an up vote is clicked, the `likes` property needs to be updated.

My question is how to determine which button is clicked. What would be a good strategy in this case for the `route()` function and the html template?

I was thinking of adding a name to each button and put `post.id` in the name, then check if `request` has it. But the number of posts are not known before hand, how should I write the `request` check in `route()` function?

My current template is as follows

```
<table class="table table-striped">
{% for post in posts %}
<tr>
<td> {{ post.id }} </td>                                                   
<td> <img src="{{ post.author.avatar(50) }}"> </td>                        
<td> <b>{{ post.body }}</b> </td>                                                                                              
<td> <button type="button" name='{{'up.'+ post.id|string}}' class="btn btn-default">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" aria-hidden="true"></span>   
</button>
{{ post.likes}} </td>  
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

and the current `route()` is like this

```
@bbs.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])                                   
def index():                                                               
    posts = Post.query.all()                                               
    return render_template('bbs/index.html', posts=posts)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A clean way to do that would be to add a data attribute, in your `button` tag and do one ajax request per upvote / downvote.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

In your case, it would be called `data-id`.

Then in your javascript, when the button is clicked, get this data attribute value, and craft your url as such :

```
/upvote/<data-id>
```

And call it using an ajax GET request (so the page doesn't refresh).

Now on flask side get the id as such :

```
@app.route('/upvote/<post_id>')
def upvote(post_id):
    print('%s upvoted' % post_id)
    # do your db update here and return a json encoded object
```

And on javascript side again, when you get your answer from flask, update your button accordingly.

Assuming you put another class in your upvote button for instance : `upvote_button` and you use jQuery, your javascript could look like that :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('.upvote_button').click(function(ev){
    var id = $(ev.currentTarget).attr('data-id');
    $.get( "/upvote/" + id, function( data ) {
      // change your button here, and remove its upvote_button class
      alert(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still struggle on this due to the lack of javascript knowledge. In my `upvote` route function, I `return json.dumps({'likes':post.likes})`. In the javascript, `alert(data)` seems to show the correct dictionary, but when I use `data.likes`, it gives `undefined`. What did I do wrong?

Comment: try : `data['likes']`